# 200 rep cap should be relaxed for Private Beta

Tags: discussion

I just hit the reputation cap, and I am not sure that's a good thing or not. Currently the privileges are relaxed. So I assume when public beta opens the privileges causing a gap in what we were once able to do for example close and re-open questions

3000     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions

Is there any reason against relaxing reputation cap during private beta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Non-technical reason:** I can't think of a good reason participants in the private beta need an edge in getting rep just on account of participating in the private beta.  All sites have to deal with the requirements being hiked up, it's just part of the process.

**Technical reason:**
Your *official* rep calculation can be viewed at any time:
https://movies.stackexchange.com/reputation

I suspect it would be a bit of a pain to maintain an exception for a short time period at the beginning of a site's life which would invariably become increasingly pointless as the site aged.

Comment: It wasn't to do with the edge, more the fact that relaxation on the privileges are dropped so you could start with 20 people with closing rights but at the end of beta end up with 5 people with closing rights but it's a good answer.

Answer (score 7):

One of the purpose of the reputation cap is keeping a user from earning an *undue* amount of reputation for a single, popular contribution. It's a throttling mechanism to keep a balance between on-going contribution and popularity.

If anything, **the reputation cap is needed *more* during the private beta.** There are far fewer post and everyone is concentrating (and voting) on what little there is to vote on. So, certainly there is an "undue" (or at least a *disproportionate*) amount of rep being doled out during the private beta.

Comment: If the cap is intended for not getting much rep for one popular contribution, why not install a cap for rep you can get on a single post?

Comment: @Mnementh I would support that, but it has already been suggested on meta SO, and declined. Jeff ran the numbers using the two different methods and it made very little difference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a relaxation of the rep-cap is really needed. At the start of a beta enough mods are looking over the site, so it's time, that users can build up reputation to gain rights. The relaxation on needed reputation to gain privilieges helps, that active participants gain privileges while the site is in beta. So in the midst of Beta the mods can start look over different sites. At the end of beta (including the open beta) enough users will have reached 10K or 20K.